# Scripts don't work in ajax content

Tags: jquery

My script to load dynamic content is this and works perfectly, the problem is that i cannot include scripts to the dynamic content. :

$('nav li a').click(function(){

```
    $(this).addClass("green");
    $('nav a').not(this).removeClass("green");  

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';  
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();  
    $('#main').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);  
    function loadContent() {  
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()); 

    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $('#content').show('slow',hideLoader()); 

    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
    }  
    return false;  

   // this is the script that i want to trigger
   $('.lightbox').lightBox();

});
```

This way doesn't work, i also try the delegate mode like this:

```
$('#content').delegate('img', 'click', light);

 var light = $('.lightbox').lightBox();
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

But you have a `return false;` before `$('.lightbox').lightBox();`. Couldn't this be the problem?

Comment: Sure it's not the problem Rahul